# how to run a console application as azure web job and window service in dotnet core

Tags: c#, windows-services, azure-webjobs, .net-core-2.2

I have console application which is working perfectly as azure web jobs in azure App Service code is given below. Now I want to deploy same console application as windows service in windows. Some client want it as windows service and some want it in azure as web-jobs. So please anyone helps me, how can i configure same console application to work as both web-job and windows service? There is one way in mind that is by passing argument in main method.
Is there any other more efficient way?
The application is developed in .net core 2.2

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CORE_ENVIRONMENT");
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                          .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                          .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", true, true)
                          .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        CustomerEnvironment = environmentName;
        Configuration = builder.Build();

        if (ServiceProvider == null)
        {
            ServiceProvider = BuildServiceProvider();
        }

        var hostbuilder = new HostBuilder()
                              .UseEnvironment(environmentName)
                              .ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
                              {
                                b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices()
                                 .AddAzureStorage()
                                 .AddTimers();
                              })
                              .ConfigureHostConfiguration(c =>
                              {
                                c.AddConfiguration(Configuration);
                              })
                              .ConfigureLogging((context, config) =>
                              {
                                config.AddSerilog(dispose: true);
                              })
                              .UseConsoleLifetime();
        ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(200, 200);
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000;
        var host = hostbuilder.Build();
        using (host)
        {
            host.RunAsync().Wait();
        }
    }
```

Comment: the way you have suggested is the only way I have been able to do it in the past. I am looking for some code, but think it was on an old machine that is long since wiped where this would have been done

Comment: Thanks @SimonPrice for your comment. Right now i am triggering web-jobs, windows service by arguments. In the future, if I find any other way to trigger these processes, i will post it in answer